# How to group strings that are one-edit distance

Tags: python, algorithm

I have a list of strings such as:

```
arr1 = ["ABC", "ABD", "ABCD", "ABCE", "ACCE", "AB"]
```

I want to group these strings into sublists, such that each sublist will only contain the strings that are x-edit-distance away. For example, 1-edit-distance away strings can be found by replacing one letter with something else. So for the list above, I want to produce:

```
arr2 = [["ABC", "ABD"], ["ABCD", "ABCE", "ACCE"], ["AB"]]
```

Is there an algorithm in the literature to solve this problem? What is an efficient way to solve this?

Edit: The edit-distance I define is a bit different in the sense that: only replacement of x letters (if x=1, only 1 letter can be different) is allowed, no addition or deletion can be done.

Comment: The only thing I can think of is iterating over a double-loop where for each item in the inner loop, I change one character at a time and compare with the value in the outer loop, but obviously it's not a clever/efficient approach.

Comment: The problem is not well defined, since one-edit distance is not a transitive property. What is the expected output for `arr1 = ["ABC", "ABD", "EBC"]`? Anyhow, instead of two nested loops use a loop over `arr1` and a `set` to perform the lookup, this makes you go from O(n^2) to O(n log n).

Comment: I may be missing something, but isn't this just grouping the word by their length? If I can only do one edit, this means that I am either shuffling the letters (length remains the same), or adding or delete letters, in which case, the length will be changed - so only those other words that are the _same length_ will be the same edit order away, right?

Comment: Can you define your edit distance more precisely.  Do you want, for example, the Levenshtein distance?

Comment: If there are more partitions of a set than permutations, then you cannot do betten than O(n log n), right?

Comment: @thefourtheye `"AB"` is not 1 'edit distance' away from `"ABCD"` ;-)

Comment: @TimCastelijns Ah, the obvious one... Sigh... Thanks for pointing out :)

Answer (score 0):

The algorithm implied by your examples may not end up being the algorithm you were looking for, but it's certainly possible:

```
editdist = lambda a, b: sum(0 if c1 == c2 else 1 for (c1, c2) in zip(a, b))
a = ["ABC", "ABD", "ABCD", "ABCE", "ACCE", "AB"]
a = list(reversed(a))
ret = []
while a:
    s = a.pop()
    for sublist in ret:
        if len(sublist[-1]) == len(s) and editdist(sublist[-1], s) == 1:
            sublist.append(s)
            s = None
            break
    if s: ret.append([s])
print ret
```

The code assumes you want the result in your question: sequences of strings such that each string in the sequence is one edit distance away from the string before it and after it.

Answer (score 0):

You can construct a graph with each strings as your vertices. There is a edge between two vertices iff the corresponding strings are x-edit-distance away. Now, just run a DFS traversal to get the grouping you need.

Let me know if you need more details.